# How to measure rising and falling edge of square wave using c-code block

Tags: measurement, programming, simulink, square, edge-detection

I have a problem in understanding how to incorporate a c-code block in order to measure the rising and falling edges of a square wave signal in Simulink. I am using a signal generator to generate a square wave and I need to measure the rising edge and falling edge of the signal using the c-script block in Simulink. How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like homework.  Could you please tell us what you've tried, and where you got stuck?

Comment: I have difficulty in writing the C code to measure the time intervals between rising edge and falling edge of the square wave generated from signal generator.

Comment: Detecting the rising edge and falling edge has been obtained by the use of a delay and comparator block. I could not figure out how to get the time values in between the edges using the c code block